# login to modx from external/other server revolution 2.2.5

Tags: modx, modx-revolution

I am pissed off with this problem from 2 days.

I am using **MODx Revolution 2.2.5 (traditional)** and want to login to modx from external server just to fetch some user details.

1) I know that runprocessor method works only if i am logged in to manager (unfortunately, that's the only way i know to login user in) So i tried IFRAME method to avoid (cross scripting) it worked perfectly but i am not able to read the data from IFRAME using javascript because of same issue, cross domain access policy.

When i try to post data using some other method like CURL, Ajax using

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

I am able to login (I see $response->response['success'] == 1) but cant access any data and it says

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object
```

Below is the snippet code i am using

```
if(isset($_POST) && count($_POST)){
    $c = array(
        'username' => $_POST['username'],
        'password' => $_POST['password']
    );
    $response = $modx->runProcessor('security/login',$c);
    if($response->response['success'] == 1){
        $user['id'] = $modx->user->get('id');
                $profile = $modx->user->getOne('Profile');
        $user['fullname'] = $profile->get('fullname');
        $user['email'] = $profile->get('email');
        echo json_encode($user);
    }else{
        echo json_encode($response->response); 
    }
}
```

2) I can use login snippet but it doesnt return output what i expect. We have ready site and we are already using login plugin so i cant even modify login plugin to respond with expected data

**How can i login to modx using api or any other method ??**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I sorted out this today, Below is the complete come that worked perfectly. 
Pay attention to

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.xyz.com");
```

Using above CORS specification you can allow 2 servers to communication.

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.xyz.com");
if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])){

// get username and password from POST array
$username = $modx->sanitizeString($_POST['username']);
$password = $modx->sanitizeString($_POST['password']);
if(trim($username) != "" and trim($password) != ""){
    // Load lexicons to show proper error messages
    if (!isset($modx->lexicon) || !is_object($modx->lexicon)) {
        $modx->getService('lexicon','modLexicon');
    }
    $modx->lexicon->load('login');

    $loginContext= isset ($scriptProperties['login_context']) ? $scriptProperties['login_context'] :
    $modx->context->get('key');

    $addContexts= isset ($scriptProperties['add_contexts']) && !empty($scriptProperties['add_contexts']) ? explode(',', $scriptProperties['add_contexts']) : array();

    $mgrEvents = ($loginContext == 'mgr');

    $givenPassword = $password;

    /** @var $user modUser */
    $user= $modx->getObjectGraph('modUser', '{"Profile":{},"UserSettings":{}}', array ('modUser.username' => $username));

    if (!$user) {
        $ru = $modx->invokeEvent("OnUserNotFound", array(
            'user' => &$user,
            'username' => $username,
            'password' => $password,
            'attributes' => array(
                'loginContext' => $loginContext,
            )
        ));

        if (!empty($ru)) {
            foreach ($ru as $obj) {
                if (is_object($obj) && $obj instanceof modUser) {
                    $user = $obj;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if (!is_object($user) || !($user instanceof modUser)) {
            //echo "cant locate account";
            echo $modx->toJSON($modx->error->failure($modx->lexicon('login_cannot_locate_account')));
            exit;
        }
    }

    if (!$user->get('active')) {
        //echo "inactivated accout";
        echo $modx->toJSON($modx->error->failure($modx->lexicon('login_user_inactive')));
            exit;
        }

    if (!$user->passwordMatches($givenPassword)) {
        if (!array_key_exists('login_failed', $_SESSION)) {
            $_SESSION['login_failed'] = 0;
        }
        if ($_SESSION['login_failed'] == 0) {
            $flc = ((integer) $user->Profile->get('failedlogincount')) + 1;
            $user->Profile->set('failedlogincount', $flc);
            $user->Profile->save();
            $_SESSION['login_failed']++;
        } else {
            $_SESSION['login_failed'] = 0;
        }
        //echo "wrong username pass";
        echo $modx->toJSON($modx->error->failure($modx->lexicon('login_username_password_incorrect')));
            exit;
        }

        $fullname =  $user->Profile->get('fullname');
        echo '{"success":true,"message":"Welcome '.$fullname.'!"}';
 }else{
        echo '{"success":false,"message":"Please enter username and password"}';
 }
```

}

Answer (score 2):

You are really attacking this problem completely wrong in my opinion. If you want to access a server/webpage from another, you don't iFrame and do it the way you are. That is hacking, and this hole will most likely be fixed in a future version.

What you SHOULD do is connecting to the database and just gather the information from the user-table.

No hacking, no "tricks", won't stop working and much safer.

Comment: Yes i agree this is hacking, so web standerds already banned all this things like cross site access, reading iframe data etc :). I knew there are ways to authenticate such requests when you own both the domains you can code cross site communication. My main problem was to login to modx without using "login" plugin, and that was making me really nuts.